# What is the probability of getting a blue ball if you pick a random colored ball from a bag?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a bag of 10 balls all different color (One of them is blue).
I want to calculate the probability of getting blue if I randomly draw it from a bag 3 times.

There are two scenarios

**Without replacement**

1/10 * 9/9 * 8/8 * 3 = 3/10

**With replacement**

1 - P(Not getting blue) = 1 - 0.9^3 = 0.271

The thing that confuses me is why can't I think of the **REPLACEMENT** case in this way

P(Getting blue for 1st draw) + P(Getting blue for 2nd draw) + P(Getting blue for 3rd draw) = 1/10 + 1/10 + 1/10 = 3/10?

Now let's assume you win 10 dollars for every blue ball you get, without replacement you can win maximum of 10 dollars but with replacement you can win maximum of 30 dollars.

According to expected value,

**Without replacement**

3/10 * 10 = 0.3

**With replacement**

0.271 * 10 = 0.271

So the game without replacement have better expected value? I feel like I am misunderstanding some important concepts.

1) What is the correct probability of getting blue ball with replacement if you can win multiple times? Can I use binomial probability for this?

2) What is the expected winning of the game with replacement if you can win multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to how much money you can win by drawing the blue ball, assuming you earn $10$ dollars every time you draw the blue ball, the scenario without replacement has only two possible outcomes:

$0$ blue balls, probability $P(X=0) = 0.7,$ gain $0.$

$1$ blue ball, probability $P(X=1) = 0.3,$ gain $10.$

The expected value of your winnings is
$$ E(10X) = 0(0.7) + 10(0.3) = 0 + 3 = 3.$$

(Note that $\frac3{10}\times 10 = 0.3 \times 10 \neq 0.3.$ Be careful what you write!)

The scenario with replacement has these possible outcomes:

$0$ blue balls, probability $P(Y=0) = \left(\frac9{10}\right)^3 = 0.729,$ gain $0.$

$1$ blue ball, probability 
$P(Y=1) = \binom31 \left(\frac1{10}\right) \left(\frac9{10}\right)^2 = 0.243,$
gain $10.$

$2$ blue balls, probability 
$P(Y=2) = \binom32 \left(\frac1{10}\right)^2 \left(\frac9{10}\right) = 0.027,$
gain $20.$

$3$ blue balls, probability $P(Y=3) = \left(\frac1{10}\right)^3 = 0.001,$
gain $30.$

Note that if we just care about whether we draw blue ball at least once, we can find the probability whether that happens either by adding up all the cases where it does happen,
$$P(Y=1) + P(Y=2) + P(Y=3) = 0.243+0.027+0.001 = 0.271,$$
or by taking $1$ and subtracting the probability that it does *not* happen,
$$1 - P(Y=0) = 1 - 0.729 = 0.271.$$

But when you gain $10$ for *each time* you draw the blue ball, the expected value of your winnings is

\begin{align}
E(10Y) &= 0(P(0)) +  10(P(1)) +  20(P(2)) +  30(P(3)) \\
&= 0 + 10(0.243) + 20(0.027) + 30(0.001) \\
&= 0 + 2.43 + 0.54 + 0.03 \\
&= 3.
\end{align}

In fact the *expected number* of blue balls drawn is exactly the same with or without replacement,
and the *expected payment* (receiving $10$ dollars each time blue is drawn) also is exactly the same in each case.

Most people would interpret "the probability of getting blue" in each scenario as the probability of getting blue *at least once.*
This probability is less in the scenario without replacement
(or to put it another way, the probability of *not even once* drawing blue is greater), 
but once you start counting the *number of times* blue is drawn (and paying $10$ dollars each time)
the chance of getting a double or triple payout makes up for the increased chance of getting no payout.

When you ask about a probability, you are asking about something that either happens or does not happen, two possible outcomes.
It is possible to set up an expected value that also deals with only two possible outcomes, but expected value very often deals with more than two possible outcomes (in your example with replacement, four possible outcomes), and in those cases it tends to give answers different than you would get by looking only at two possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. I ran a simulation (10 million times) and I counted the number of times blue appear. I get about 30%. If we call 0.271 as probability of getting blue at least once. What do we call 0.3 as? probability of getting blue ____ ?

Comment: We call it "expected number of times blue is drawn". We don't use the word "probability."

Comment: I still don't understand Why can't i think of replacement case in this way ? P(Getting blue for 1st draw) + P(Getting blue for 2nd draw) + P(Getting blue for 3rd draw) = 1/10 + 1/10 + 1/10 = 3/10?. I got 0.3 too, is this a coincidence?

Comment: Because getting blue in 1st/2nd/3rd draw are not disjoint events (thus your sum is not correct)!

Comment: @Zanko In general, _expected value_ can always be added the way you say, but _probability_ only adds that way under special circumstances. Let's change the payment plan: you draw three times, and the first time you draw blue you get $10$ dollars, but you don't get any extra payment for drawing blue a second or third time. Now there are just two outcomes, $0$ dollars or $10$ dollars. Is it intuitively obvious that this game is not as good for you as the one that pays you another $10$ dollars if you draw blue again, and yet another $10$ dollars if you draw blue a third time?

Comment: Hi instead of doing 0(P(0))+10(P(1))+20(P(2))+30(P(3)) to calculate expected winning. I was wondering why this work as well. Chance for blue ball 1/10. So expected earning for each draw is 1/10*10 = 1; There are three draws so 1*3 = 3. This is much easier to list out all the cases right?

Comment: Yes, that's called "linearity of expectation," and it has a name because it's a very special and useful fact. It can make difficult problems easy. I did the more complicated version in this answer because not everyone has studied linearity of expectation by the time they work on problems like this, and also because it helps illustrate how the $0.271$ probability applies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the game without replacement have bave better expected value, as with drawing not-blue balls the probability of drawing blue gets higher.

**Hint**

In with replacement scenario, once again try to calculate probability of the opposite event.

1) If you mean the probability of getting at least one blue ball, then $0.271$. You can use binomial.

2) If you mean expected number of blue ball drawed it is $ 3 * \frac{1}{10} * \frac{9}{10}*\frac{9}{10}+ 3*2* \frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{10}  * \frac{9}{10} + 3*  (\frac{1}{10})^3 $

Comment: Why can't i think of replacement case in this way ? P(Getting blue for 1st draw) + P(Getting blue for 2nd draw) + P(Getting blue for 3rd draw) = 1/10 + 1/10 + 1/10 = 3/10?

Comment: Because in each of these "singular" probabilities you already include probabilities of success in two/three draws, thus you duplicate these chances.

If $X_i$- getting blue in $i$-th draw, then you should use

$P(X_1) + P(X_2) + P(X_3) - P(X_1 \cap X_2) - P(X_1 \cap X_3) - P(X_2 \cap X_3)  + P(X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3) = 3 * \frac{1}{10}  - 3 * \frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{1000} = 0.271 $

Comment: The expected number of times blue is drawn is _exactly the same_ in both games. Your calculation at the end has $\frac9{10}$ twice in the second term, whereas it should occur only once and $\frac1{10}$ should occur twice; correct this and the sum comes out to $0.3$ as it should. It's unclear what you mean by "expected value" in your first paragraph; if you mean "probability it happens at least once," that's a strange way to express it.